# Training time for model with additional 4 dense layers same as without

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tpu

I am trying to troubleshoot my model which produces nonsensical predictions..
In the process I added another dense layer and the train timing kept the same as without it. So I added 4 x 512 neurons dense layers and the time is the same..

I use TPU v3 but still - calculating 4 extra fully connected networks with 512 neurons each should take some additional time, I expect.

**Can anyone please help explaining this or at least give an idea for investigation**

***EDIT:*** number of trainable params for LSTM + 1 Dense = 4 mil; LSTM + 4 Dense = 5mil

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(window_size, inputs_n), return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.LSTM(neurons))
model.add(layers.Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(outputs_n, activation=activation))

TPU_ADDRESS1 = 'grpc://10.240.2.2:8470'

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
print(model.metrics_names)

tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model, 
        strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
            tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu = [TPU_ADDRESS1])))
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_input (InputLayer)      (None, 1024, 7)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 1024, 512)         1064960   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1024, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 512)               2099200   
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 2052      
=================================================================
Total params: 4,216,836
Trainable params: 4,216,836
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Something like that might happen if the latency contribution of dense layers is not signifficant on the first place. Can you compare runtime of the models with different number of Dense layers but wihtout lstm layers?

Comment: its a completely different solution and would take some time to reimplement. however it processes 1000 batches in 1 sec. 10 sec for a day worth data.. if what you say is the case then dense layers take less than 0.2 sec I'd expect.. is it realistic?

Comment: Instead, you can add another LSTM layer and if it will increase runtime significantly, than probably dense layers are the largest contributors. LSTM are infamous for running pretty slow